# Why won't my Dwolla button appear on my ASPX page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, client-side, dwolla

I have a VB ASP.NET web application and I'm trying to utilize Dwolla.  Dwolla helpfully does not have any VB code to share on how to accomplish this, so I've done the best I can to make this work.  I have a test HTML page with a script tag in it that works fine, and I can copy and paste it into my application, and it works, but I need to change some of the elements dynamically using variables.

I'm not accomplished with JS, so any help is appreciated here.  In my code behind, I've written the following code:

```
Dim ScriptTxt As String
        ScriptTxt = "src = 'https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js' class='dwolla_button' type='text/javascript' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -key = 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -redirect = 'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -Label = 'Pay This Invoice' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -name = 'Invoice' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -description = '" & SessItemDescr & "Invoice' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -amount = '" & SessInvoiceAmt & "' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -shipping = '0.00' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -tax = '0.00' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -guest - checkout = 'true' "
        ScriptTxt = ScriptTxt & "Data -Type = 'simple'"
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "Dwolla", ScriptTxt, True)
```

When the app runs, the button that is supposed to be generated by this script doesn't appear.  There's no error displayed, and none of the code shows the squiggly line.

This is the static HTML code that works (although all the values, in the end, need to be dynamic):

```
<script
  src="https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js" class="dwolla_button" type="text/javascript"
  data-key="ReH8AkxCe/Ca//AoR+840H39WZnhLbiOUNw/pitA5DN1xLKbxZ"
  data-redirect="http://www.connectedperformancepc.com/pay_status.aspx"
  data-label="Pay This Invoice Now"
  data-name="INVOICE PAYMENT"
  data-description="Invoice Payment - Includes all taxes and fees"
  data-amount="1"
  data-shipping="0"
  data-tax="0"
  data-guest-checkout="true"
  data-type="simple"
>
</script>
```

The Dwolla button is supposed to appear at the bottom of the page, on top of the footer (coded in the master page file). What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?  I really need this done soon, as I'm switching from PayPal and currently can't take payments online (unless I want to pay out the nose for PayPal - Dwolla is only 25 cents for transactions over $10).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there! I work for Dwolla and I want to help you - but I need some more information. When you say that the button does not appear, have you checked the source to see if your code is throwing the button onto the page? 

If it works statically, then I believe the issue lies with the logic/method responsible for displaying the button. In your browser - right click and view your page's source, and look to see if the button is there or not, etc. 

Let me know!

Comment: Hi David, no the button code isn't there.  Only some odd script tag information I'll post here.  It's considerably different from the HTML code I put in my question above.  I'll put the source in another comment.

Comment: @DavidS.  Source: <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
src = 'https://www.dwolla.com/scripts/button.min.js' class='dwolla_button' type='text/javascript' Data -key = 'ReH8AkxCe/Ca//AoR+840H39WZnhLbiOUNw/pitA5DN1xLKbxZ' Data -redirect = 'http://www.connectedperformancepc.com/pay_status.aspx' Data -Label = 'Pay This Invoice' Data -name = 'Invoice' Data -description = 'PRIVATEInvoice' Data -amount = '27.56' Data -shipping = '0.00' Data -tax = '0.00' Data -guest - checkout = 'true' Data -Type = 'simple'//]]>
</script>

Comment: @DavidS.  Basically, it looks like all of the script tag elements are encapsulated with in the <SCRIPT> tag itself before the closing ">", whereas wht my code is generating looks like a bunch of jibberish.  I need to know how to generate this in y asp code so that I can make the button appear and pass all the variables to Dwolla correctly.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidS.  Also, since you work for Dwolla, maybe you can answer this too.  Even when I use the HTML code that works, I don't have the option to checkout with a Dwolla account, even though the allow guest checkout option is enabled.  Any idea why this is the case, and how to fix it?  I really don't wnt all of my customers to have to create a Dwolla account.